# query pivot with two word with space in column

Tags: mysql

my query :

```
  set @sql = NULL;
select
  group_concat(distinct
    concat(
   'max(if(first.study = ''',
  study, ''', first.avg_scores, NULL)) as ',
  study
)
  ) into @sql
from `table`;

SET @sql = concat('select first.name,
              ', @sql, ' 
               from `table` first
                 join `table` second
                   on first.name = second.name
               group by first.name');

prepare stmt from @sql;
execute stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;
```

when data in column "study"

```
=================================
  name  |  study  |  avg_scores
=================================
  alfa      c         75
  beta      c         70
  alfa     php        85
  beta     php        90
```

and result : its true.

```
===========================
  name   |   c   |  php
===========================
  alfa      75      85
  beta      70      90
```

the problem when i have data in table like this :

```
===================================
  name  |  study     |  avg_scores
===================================
  alfa    junior c         75
  beta    junior c         70
  alfa    junior php       85
  beta    junior php       90
```

error : 
  "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version 
  for the right syntax to use near 'c,max(if(first.study = 'junior php', 
  first.avg_scores, NULL)) as junior php ' at line 2: prepare stmt from @sql"

so : how to fix my query ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you need to escape the identifiers, because a column name cannot have a space.  The following uses double quotes for the name (you can also use backticks):

```
set @sql = NULL;
select group_concat(distinct concat('max(if(first.study = ''', study,
                                    ''', first.avg_scores, NULL)) as "', study, '"'
---------------------------------------------------------------------^ ----------^    
                                   )
                   ) into @sql
from `table`;

SET @sql = concat('select first.name, ', @sql, '
                   from `table` first join `table` second on first.name = second.name
                   group by first.name');
```